# Remote Debugging visual studio 2010: Breakpoints do not load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharepoint-2010, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug my webpart. I can successfully attach to the remote process but my breakpoints do not load. Can anyone help me?

PS I've checked the "modules" but my assembly is not loaded there.

PPS My .dll is GAC deployed and I am the admin of both the dev and server.

PPS The .pdb files are on the bin folder of the application: inetpub/.../9090/bin
I was wondering if I can force the "modules" to load a given .dll. Is it?

Comment: Does Visual Studio have full red circles for your breakpoints? If not, hover over the hollowed out circle and see if it gives you any messages. Typically debugging fails if it cannot find any PDB files.

Comment: yes, there is a circle but they are not "filled"... and the pdb files are on the bin folder of the application folder... the dlls are on the GAC

Answer (score 4):

Is debugging enabled in the `web.config` of the target web application?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**UPDATE**

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx

The section on  PDB loading says:

> The first place searched is the directory where the binary was loaded.
>   If the PDB file is not there, the
>   second place the debugger looks is the
>   hard coded build directory embedded in
>   the Debug Directories in the PE
>   file.If the PDB file is not in the
>   first two locations, and a Symbol
>   Server is set up for the on the
>   machine, the debugger looks in the
>   Symbol Server cache directory.
>   Finally, if the debugger does not find
>   the PDB file in the Symbol Server
>   cache directory, it looks in the
>   Symbol Server itself.

You need to move the PDB into the same folder in the GAC, or into the same path that you built the assembly from.

Use this method to enable viewing the GAC folders

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/01/14/how-to-copy-an-assembly-from-the-gac.aspx